# Strange error when logging into Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, login

Every time I log in, for some reason, I get a little box that pops up in the middle of my screen that says:

`invalid option: -session`

It just started yesterday and I'm not sure what is causing it. I'm running the 64bit version of Xubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

Comment: A screenshot could help

Comment: @Jason Smith plase paste the contents of .xinitrc

Comment: OK, I found the answer to this issue.  I don't remember what it was off hand it's been so long ago but this question can be closed.

Answer (score -1):

I've got same problem on Xubuntu 12.10. Deleting the `~/.cache/sessions` folder helps. I hope somebody will use that answer.